# How to create a Edittext in action bar in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-actionbar

Can we use an edit text in action bar?
After reading lot of resources in Google i could not find how to create an edit text in action bar.
Can anyone tell me how do i do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can set a custom `View` for the `ActionBar` like this:

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
```

You can then find `Views` from the custom `View` in the `ActionBar` like this:

```
View actionBarView = getActionBar().getCustomView();
EditText editText = (EditText) acitonBarView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Or you can just directly set a `View` instance as custom `View` like this:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(context);
getActionBar().setCustomView(editText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

[First url](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-add-custom-view-actionbar/)     [Second url](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-custom-action-view-to-action-bar-in-android/)